# HTML and Javascript button not working

Tags: javascript, html, button, pong

I am trying to make a webpage to store all my games on i just started and i've been trying to make a button to load my pong game but when I press the button nothing happens here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            canvas {
                position: absolute;
                margin: auto;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <h1>Games</h1>
```

button code

```
        <input id="Pong" type="button" value="Pong" onclick="go();" />
```

pong code

```
        <script>
            function go(){
            var WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 600, pi = Math.PI;
            var UpArrow = 38, DownArrow = 40;
            var canvas, ctx, keystate;
            var player, ai, ball, score;

            player = {
                x: null,
                y: null,
                width: 20,
                height: 100,

                update: function(){
                    if(keystate[UpArrow]) this.y -= 7;
                    if(keystate[DownArrow]) this.y += 7;
                },
                draw: function(){
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
            };
            ai = {
                x: null,
                y: null,
                width: 20,
                height: 100,

                update: function(){
                    var desty = ball.y - (this.height - ball.side)*0.5;
                    this.y += (desty - this.y) * 0.1;
                },
                draw: function(){
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
            };
            ball = {
                x: null,
                y: null,
                vel: null,
                side: 20,
                speed: 9,

                serve: function(side){
                    var r = Math.random();
                    this.x = side===1 ? player.x :  ai.x - this.side;
                    this.y = (HEIGHT - this.side)*r;
                    score.count += 1;

                    var phi = 0.1*pi*(1 - 2*r);
                    this.vel = {
                        x: side*this.speed*Math.cos(phi),
                        y: this.speed*Math.sin(phi)
                    };
                score = {
                    x: null,
                    y: null,
                    count: 0,
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10,


                    update: function(){
                        Console.log(this.count);
                    },
                    draw: function(){
                        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
            };
                },
                update: function(){
                    this.x += this.vel.x;
                    this.y += this.vel.y;

                    if(0 > this.y || this.y+this.side > HEIGHT){
                        var offset = this.vel.y < 0 ? 0 - this.y : HEIGHT - (this.y+this.side);
                        this.y += 2*offset;
                        this.vel.y *= -1;
                    }

                    var AABBIntersect = function(ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh){
                        return ax < bx+bw && ay < by+bh && bx < ax+aw && by < ay+ah;
                    };

                    var pdle = this.vel.x < 0 ? player : ai;
                    if(AABBIntersect(pdle.x, pdle.y, pdle.width, pdle.height, this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side)){
                        this.x = pdle===player ? player.x+player.width : ai.x - this.side;
                        var n = (this.y + this.side - pdle.y)/(pdle.height+this.side);
                        var phi = 0.25*pi*(2*n - 1);

                        var smash = Math.abs(phi) > 0.2*pi ? 1.5 : 1;
                        this.vel.x = smash*(pdle === player ? 1 : -1)*this.speed*Math.cos(phi);
                        this.vel.y = smash*this.speed*Math.sin(phi);
                    }

                    if(0 > this.x+this.side || this.x > WIDTH){
                        this.serve(pdle === player ? 1 : -1);
                    }
                },
                draw: function(){
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side);
                }
            };

            function main(){
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = WIDTH;
                canvas.height = HEIGHT;
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                keystate = {};
                document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
                    keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
                });
                document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
                    delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
                });

                init();

                var loop = function(){
                    update();
                    draw();
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
                };
                window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
            }

            function init(){
                player.x = player.width;
                player.y = (HEIGHT - player.height)/2;

                ai.x = WIDTH - (player.width + ai.width);
                ai.y = (HEIGHT - ai.height)/2;

               ball.serve(1);
            }

            function update(){
                ball.update();
                player.update();
                ai.update();
            }

            function draw(){

                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                ctx.save();
                ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

                ball.draw();
                player.draw();
                ai.draw();

                var w = 4;
                var x = (WIDTH - w) * 0.5;
                var y = 0;
                var step = HEIGHT/15;
                while (y < HEIGHT){
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y + step * 0.25, w, step * 0.5);
                    y += step;
                }

                ctx.restore();
            }

            main();
        }
        </script>
```

end of pong code

```
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You define `score` _inside_ `ball.serve`, after you use a non-existent property of it. You should define it outside. Also, it’s `console.log`, not `Console.log`. Next, you call `ball.update` which doesn’t exist. Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and read the errors. Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merely took @Xufox's solutions and wrote them out.  Also serperated the JS, CSS, and HTML.  Enjoy

```js
   function go(){
     score = {
                    x: null,
                    y: null,
                    count: 0,
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10,


                    update: function(){
                        console.log(this.count);
                    },
                    draw: function(){
                        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
            };
            var WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 600, pi = Math.PI;
            var UpArrow = 38, DownArrow = 40;
            var canvas, ctx, keystate;
            var player, ai, ball, score;

            player = {
                x: null,
                y: null,
                width: 20,
                height: 100,

                update: function(){
                    if(keystate[UpArrow]) this.y -= 7;
                    if(keystate[DownArrow]) this.y += 7;
                },
                draw: function(){
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
            };
            ai = {
                x: null,
                y: null,
                width: 20,
                height: 100,

                update: function(){
                    var desty = ball.y - (this.height - ball.side)*0.5;
                    this.y += (desty - this.y) * 0.1;
                },
                draw: function(){
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
            };
            ball = {
                x: null,
                y: null,
                vel: null,
                side: 20,
                speed: 9,

                serve: function(side){
                    var r = Math.random();
                    this.x = side===1 ? player.x :  ai.x - this.side;
                    this.y = (HEIGHT - this.side)*r;
                    score.count += 1;

                    var phi = 0.1*pi*(1 - 2*r);
                    this.vel = {
                        x: side*this.speed*Math.cos(phi),
                        y: this.speed*Math.sin(phi)
                    };
        
                },
                update: function(){
                    this.x += this.vel.x;
                    this.y += this.vel.y;

                    if(0 > this.y || this.y+this.side > HEIGHT){
                        var offset = this.vel.y < 0 ? 0 - this.y : HEIGHT - (this.y+this.side);
                        this.y += 2*offset;
                        this.vel.y *= -1;
                    }

                    var AABBIntersect = function(ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh){
                        return ax < bx+bw && ay < by+bh && bx < ax+aw && by < ay+ah;
                    };

                    var pdle = this.vel.x < 0 ? player : ai;
                    if(AABBIntersect(pdle.x, pdle.y, pdle.width, pdle.height, this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side)){
                        this.x = pdle===player ? player.x+player.width : ai.x - this.side;
                        var n = (this.y + this.side - pdle.y)/(pdle.height+this.side);
                        var phi = 0.25*pi*(2*n - 1);

                        var smash = Math.abs(phi) > 0.2*pi ? 1.5 : 1;
                        this.vel.x = smash*(pdle === player ? 1 : -1)*this.speed*Math.cos(phi);
                        this.vel.y = smash*this.speed*Math.sin(phi);
                    }

                    if(0 > this.x+this.side || this.x > WIDTH){
                        this.serve(pdle === player ? 1 : -1);
                    }
                },
                draw: function(){
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side);
                }
            };

            function main(){
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = WIDTH;
                canvas.height = HEIGHT;
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                keystate = {};
                document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
                    keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
                });
                document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
                    delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
                });

                init();

                var loop = function(){
                    update();
                    draw();
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
                };
                window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
            }

            function init(){
                player.x = player.width;
                player.y = (HEIGHT - player.height)/2;

                ai.x = WIDTH - (player.width + ai.width);
                ai.y = (HEIGHT - ai.height)/2;

               ball.serve(1);
            }

            function update(){
                ball.update();
                player.update();
                ai.update();
            }

            function draw(){

                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                ctx.save();
                ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

                ball.draw();
                player.draw();
                ai.draw();

                var w = 4;
                var x = (WIDTH - w) * 0.5;
                var y = 0;
                var step = HEIGHT/15;
                while (y < HEIGHT){
                    ctx.fillRect(x, y + step * 0.25, w, step * 0.5);
                    y += step;
                }

                ctx.restore();
            }

            main();
        }
```

```css
 canvas {
                position: absolute;
                margin: auto;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <h1>Games</h1>

        <input id="Pong" type="button" value="Pong" onclick="go();" />




        </center>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```